# How do I get Key value pairs output in the form of dictionary from layoutlmV1 model such that the question is keys and the answer is values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, ocr

I am using the below Notebook in order to get the output as key-value pair after getting questioned and answered from the inference.
The questions should be key and the answer should be the value of it.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/LayoutLM/Fine_tuning_LayoutLMForTokenClassification_on_FUNSD.ipynb

The code I tried

```
layout_details = []
for prediction, box in zip(true_predictions, true_boxes):
    predicted_label = iob_to_label(prediction).lower()
    layout_details.append((predicted_label, prediction, box, label2color[predicted_label])) 

for i, j in zip(words[0], layout_details[1:-1]):
    print(i, j)
```

Is there any referenced code for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific open source code available. However you can use the following approach that we tried.

1. Store key and value in single list.
2. Start with key and try to match adjacent value with it using distance between or angle between two using bounding box information.
3. Use the previous and next work information to elevate the binding higher.